# How to set different UITableViewCell heights based on the UIImageView height?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I need to set the height for the Cells based on the height of the uiimageview which is `scaledHeight` variable
im getting images from Parse like so in my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
PFFile *userImageFile = object[@"image"];
    [userImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!error) {
           // UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
           // imageView.image = image;


            UIImageView *test = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 320)];
            test.image = image;

            CGSize imgSize = image.size;
            CGFloat ratio = test.frame.size.width/imgSize.width;
            CGFloat scaledHeight = imgSize.height * ratio;

            [test setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.window.frame.size.width, scaledHeight)];

            NSLog(@"HEIGHT:%f",scaledHeight);

            [cell addSubview:test];

        }
    } progressBlock:^(int percentDone)
    {

    }];
```

how can i set `scaledHeight` inside `heightForRowAtIndexPath` as `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is run before `CellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 1):

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //This is for same height of image view
     uitableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellforRowAtIndexPath : indexPath];
     return cell.imageView.size.height;
   //If you have different sizes of images then store all those image in array and then calculate the height.

}
```

Comment: how would i calculate the image height inside `heightForRow..`

Comment: imageView.size.height will give you height.

Comment: how would i do that if the imageView is set in cellForRow?

Comment: this would mean i would have to subclass it as a custom cell?

Answer (score 1):

**1. Try to set default heights in Array**

```
- (void)setDefaultRowHeights {
    self.imageHeights = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.imageURLs.count];
    for (int i = 0; i < self.imageURLs.count; i++) {
        self.imageHeights[i] = @(self.tableView.rowHeight);
    }
}
```

**2. In cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *imageURL = self.imageURLs[indexPath.row];
    __weak TableViewCell *weakCell = cell;
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [cell.mainImageView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]]
                              placeholderImage:[UIImage new]
                                       success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                                           weakCell.mainImageView.image = image;

                                          // Calculate Heights
                                           NSInteger oldHeight = [weakSelf.imageHeights[indexPath.row] integerValue];
                                           NSInteger newHeight = (int)image.size.height;

                                           // Update table row height if image is in different size
                                           if (oldHeight != newHeight) {
                                               weakSelf.imageHeights[indexPath.row] = @(newHeight);
                                               [weakSelf.tableView beginUpdates];
                                               [weakSelf.tableView endUpdates];
                                           }
                                       } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                           NSLog(@"Error:");
                                       }];

    return cell;
}
```

**3. In heightForRowAtIndexPath**

```
   - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        return [self.imageHeights[indexPath.row] integerValue];
    }
```

Comment: doesnt this not work because heightForRowAtIndexPath is loaded before CellforRowAtIndexPath, im downloading images in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 1):

Since you are loading image asynchronously by default you have to return some default value in heightForRowAtIndexPath method. Once image gets loaded you have to reload only that particular row. Now again heightForRowAtIndexPath will be called there you have return actual height of the image. You can also add some animation while reloading particular row, so that UI transition will be smooth.

Comment: example on how to do it?

Comment: tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath.init(forItem: 0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

Answer (score 0):

Get the image size bounds height and return it on heightForRowAtIndexPath. That will dynamically differ your height according to your image height size.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
   //Assign your url
   NSURL* aURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"];

   //get data of that url image.
   NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:aURL];

   //get image 
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

   //return it's bounding height (bounds return the area of height image requires.)
   return image.bounds.height;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take one mutablearray(`NSMutableArray *arrayHeights`) by default this array has number of object equal to total number of rows. and they all have set "0" value

and `heightForRowAtIndexPath` return

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return   [arrayHeights[indexPath.row] floatValue] + 50.0; // 50 is default space set it according your requirements  
}
```

now when you get result from getDataInBackgroundWithBlock replace object of arrayHeights with image height for that particular index and reload that cell

```
PFFile *userImageFile = object[@"image"];
    [userImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!error) {
           // UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
           // imageView.image = image;


            UIImageView *test = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 320)];
            test.image = image;

            CGSize imgSize = image.size;
            CGFloat ratio = test.frame.size.width/imgSize.width;
            CGFloat scaledHeight = imgSize.height * ratio;
            [arrContactList replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:scaledHeight]];
            [test setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.window.frame.size.width, scaledHeight)];

            NSLog(@"HEIGHT:%f",scaledHeight);

            [cell addSubview:test];
// reload cell
        }
    } progressBlock:^(int percentDone)
    {

    }];
```